# Ice-World / Cryo-World Settlement (amorphous cryolava / cryomagma)

Tags: hard-science, space-colonization, cryogenics, lava

I was watching a program about the New Horizons space probe and was fascinated by the new revelations about cryolava/cryomagma, and the [amorphous planes covering Pluto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluto#Geology)(98% nitrogen ice).

I'm wondering how this might affect the idea of a human colony on an ice-world/cryo-world.  In particular:

- How would you keep structures from slowly sinking into the surface
  of a planet completely covered by cryolava?
- How fast would this sinking occur?

I'm assuming the habitat will need to be kept warm, and would therefore accelerate the process.

I imagine for small habitats, this might not be a big deal, as they could be on wheels and roll along the surface, although this could scale poorly to larger settlements/cities

#### Addition

**Quick freezing point chart from wikipedia data**

```
pure       freezing 
substance  point 
H2O        273.2 °K 
CO2        216.6 °K
NH3        195.5°K
CH4        90.70 °K
CO         68.13 °K
N2         63.15 °K
O2         54.4°K
H2         14.0°K

approx. surface temp. Pluto(for reference): 33°K - 55°K
```

Comment: Somewhat related maybe: [worldbuilding.SE: Landships in an Ice World](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/58616/landships-in-an-ice-world?newreg=4aa77cb49e4342fd8a57969311d5ecef)

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE kipbits.  I did a very light edit on your question and also removed the [tag:science-based] tag since [tag:hard-science] supersedes it.

Comment: thanks! i guess all the choices sort of confused me...

Answer (score 5):

Amorphous means non-crystalline, not non-solid.  Glass is amorphous, and it's solid enough to hold a load for a long time at room temperature (the myth about sagging in centuries-old stained glass windows is just that -- a myth).  Likewise, amorphous ice (whether water ice, ammonia, clathrate, or even oxygen) will be solid enough not to flow or creep noticeably, so long as the temperature stays below the freezing temperature of the substance.

As long as your habitats are insulated so the surface(s) contacting the amorphous ice plain are below the melting or sublimation temperature, you needn't worry about the habs sinking into the surface.  If they get too warm on the bottom, it won't matter whether the material they're standing on is crystalline or amorphous, it'll still melt (and, in a vacuum, immediately flash to vapor).  Sinking won't be subtle at that point, if there's  enough heat reserve to boil off a lot of the supporting material.

Comment: Maybe... I'm not sure I agree... I've seen my fair share of old warped glass, and the surface of pluto is [98 percent nitrogen ice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluto#Geology)

Comment: I'm thinking it might not be a problem initially, but perhaps it might start sinking, sort of like New Orleans. I guess its a question of speed.

Comment: Water ice, even when crystalline, flows, too (c.f. *glacier*) -- but that doesn't mean you can't build on it (c.f. *Little America*, *McMurdo Station*).  @kipbits Even nitrogen ice won't be a problem as long as the legs under the habs are cold enough.

Comment: I think you mean [Amundsen–Scott Station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amundsen–Scott_South_Pole_Station), but I suppose you have a point... Still what about larger settlements/cities, like a cryogenic Manhattan?

Comment: It's tempting to suggest that by the time the technology exists to move or support that kind of population on Pluto or some other cryo-body, either we'll have given up living on planets entirely, or be able to chill a baseplate enough not to have to worry about it.

Comment: Then again, heat leaking through the foundations could be a nifty "technology failing" or sabotage/terrorism plotline...

Comment: You know, I hate that "continue in chat" thing -- it's how to KILL discussion, not how to keep it neat.

Comment: I like gravity, although you made me think of this: [Frozen soil wall](https://www7.tepco.co.jp/responsibility/decommissioning/action/w_management/land_side-e.html), but would this work if the glacier itself is melting/refreezing?

Comment: this is kind of going on long... water ice isn't a good metaphor(it is crystalline). it more like trying to rest something heavy on a bowl of molten hot plastic, only the bowl is miles potentially 100's deep.

Comment: I should probably put this back here: [continue in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91874/discussion-between-kipbits-and-zeiss-ikon) I'm told it's standard procedure these days...;P

Comment: It is standard.  Doesn't mean I like it.  This will all get deleted at some future time, anyway.  Anyway, I'm out of anything to add.

Comment: @kipbits I was under the impression that old glass is warped simply because making glass panes flat is really much harder than you'd think and old methods for doing it created glass that is warped from the beginning. (<-obviously off-topic)

Comment: @VilleNiemi You may be correct, I haven't really thought about it, but that doesn't change the fact that this cryolava/magma as found on pluto would be like a soft putty, although perhaps flowing at a snail's pace. It's like heating up ABS or some other amorphous plastic, only on a mountainous scale.

Comment: Come to think about it, given the very low freezing temperature of pure Nitrogen, and the impurities giving it amorphous properties, wouldn't a better analogy be molten/near molten glass. Glass doesn't have a defined melting temp, because it is amorphous, although I expect it flows faster as it gets hotter...?

Comment: [chemistry.SE-A: Melting Point of Amorphous Solids](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/69251)

Comment: @kipbits Really only relevant in that the cryomagma may have an indistinct melting point, like glass, rather than a sharp one, like snow.  Just like glass, if it's cold enough, it's "solid" in the conventional sense.

Comment: i've edited in a melting point chart. supposedly impurities will lower the melting temp and make it amorphous, N2 is getting pretty cold to freeze, although I guess there are lower melting substances(Helium). Surface temperatures of pluto are in that range though; I think it would be near molten. Pluto only has parts of its surface covered, but i can imagine a planet/planetoid that is completely covered in molten cryo-magma.

Comment: You might want to look up a vapor pressure chart for nitrogen, too.  If that pressure is higher than zero (and it is), the nitrogen will just sublimate rather than flow, unless the impurities keep it from evaporating (unlikely, in my understanding).

Answer (score 1):

**Buoyancy.**

[image: styrofoam pontoon]

Your ice world settlements are built on giant hydrogen-puffed Styrofoam pontoons.  Each building and its pontoon is lighter than the liquid below and so it will not sink.  Once could use the same method for building on a Minnesota lake of unpredictable April frozenness - if liquid or slush, your building floats.  If solid your building sits.

The styrofoam also provides extra insulation between hot dwelling and frozen substrate.

Comment: titanic pontoons for floating cities I like it!

Comment: Worlds this cold have effectively zero atmosphere; nothing with significant vapor pressure can stay liquid (that includes nitrogen and oxygen above their melting point)..  There'll be no liquid to float on.

Comment: is that right? wouldn't there still be some buoyancy force from the displace magma, assuming it doesn't evaporate..? It's like how they say to lie down when stuck in quick sand?

Comment: I like the pontoon approach, although I'm still thinking it might have problems scaling to larger/megalithic structures; I'm not sure they could put the Burj Khalifa on pontoons ...like what if this world becomes a "hot destination", and real estate shoots way up?

Comment: I imagine this cryo-magma could go pretty deep, I'm pretty sure a standard foundation would be impossible. need to do more research...

Comment: @ZeissIkon unless its orbit is significantly elliptical